# Method does not exist or incorrect signature? Unit test fail

Tags: apex

```
public static String cContact(contact newContact,string acctId,string acctType)
{ 
    Savepoint sp = null;
    List<Profile> profileLst = [Select Id,Name from Profile where Name in ('Community','Community User')];
    Map<String,Id> mapProfileByName = new Map<String,Id>();
    for(profile p:profileLst){
          mapProfileByName.put(p.Name,p.Id);
      }
  sp = Database.setSavepoint();
```

> // following error : Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   void cContact(Contact, Id, String)

Comment: The exception must be on other part of your code where you are invoking the referenced cContact method. Could you enhance the description a little bit?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. As Ideasforce said, providing more information here will be helpful (generally, the more specific and detailed you can be, the better). The signature of the method you've provided is `String cContact(Contact, String, String)`, but the error you've given us says you're trying to call a `void cContact(Contact, Id, String)`. An Id _should_ be able to be coerced into a String. Seeing the code that is calling this `cContact()` method (with enough surrounding context) is probably needed to get you an accurate answer.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are calling into a void method when this is a string method definition. Update the calling location to return a string or change this to be a void method.